# Why doesn't simplifying $i$ using division not seem to work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I was wondering why simplifying $i$ doesn't seem to work with division the same way it does multiplication.

For example, the following works:

$i^4 = 1$

$i^{31} = (i^4)^7 \cdot i^3 = 1 \cdot (-1) \cdot i = -i$

But not when applying the rules of exponents to this concept with division:

$i^{31} = \cfrac{(i^4)^8}{i^1} = \cfrac{1}{i} = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1}} \ne -i$

Have I messed things up with the rules?

Comment: $1/i=-i{{{{}}}}$

Comment: How to format your questions: type `$i^{-31i}$` to get $i^{-31i}$ and `$\sqrt{-1}$` to get $\sqrt{-1}$.  To get an expression all on one line, like $$(i^4)^7\cdot i^3$$ you need to type double `$`'s like `$$(i^4)^7 \cdot i^3$$`.  Doing so makes your questions/ answers much more readable.  For more info, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The number $i$ works perfectly fine with division: $1/i = -i$  and the simplest way to prove it is to note that $i(-i)=-i^2=1$.  The issue you are having has another source.  It come from the equality $\sqrt{-1} =i$.  Then you have $$ 1/i = 1/\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{1/-1}= \sqrt{-1}= i \neq -i$$ This is wrong!  But, where is the error?  The error is that IF $a\geq 0$, then $\sqrt{a}$ is the positive square root of $a$ and  $-\sqrt{a}$ is the negative square root of $a$, BUT this does not apply if $a<0$ or $a$ is complex.  In fact, $\sqrt{-1}$ is multi-valued, it has two values: $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to mention that we can produce incorrect results from $i=\sqrt{-1}$ just using multiplication.  For instance: 
$$-i=(-1).i= i.i.i = \sqrt{-1}.\sqrt{-1}.\sqrt{-1}= \sqrt{(-1).(-1).(-1)}= \sqrt{-1}=i$$
The issue is the same I explained in my comment above: $\sqrt{-1}$  has actually two values $i$ and $-i$ (and we can not distinguish between them as "positive" square root and "negative" square root).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$(-i) \cdot i=1$, so the inverse of $i$ is: $\dfrac{1}{i}=-i$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$
\frac 1 i=\frac 1 i\cdot \frac i i
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\color{blue}{\cfrac{1}{i} = \cfrac{1}{i} \times \cfrac{i}{i}} = \color{#F80}{\cfrac{i}{i^2}=\cfrac{i}{-1}}=-i$

In the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ step we have multiplied by $1$; since $\cfrac{i}{i}=1$.

In the $\color{#F80}{\mathrm{orange}}$ step we have used the definition of $i$ such that $$i=\sqrt{-1}$$ so $$i^2=-1$$

Comment: @marc Is there something else?

Comment: In fact, $\sqrt{-1}$  is multivalued.  It has two values $i$ and $-i$.  Your solution is OK because you actually used only $i^2=-1$. (See my comment below the question).

Comment: @Ramiro Okay, thanks again Ramio